# Does Azure ML Studio not working with Chrome/Firefox?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

See attached, is it because I am on Chrome/Firefox? I am currently on a Macbook, so I can't really test this out on Edge browser. Why does Microsoft build something that won't work for other browsers?

[image]

Comment: I don't think you would get an answer to this here. I would suggest raising this issue on Azure UserVoice Forum.

Comment: @GauravMantri Cool, will move my question there. Thanks. Did not know that place existed.

Comment: @GauravMantri I think they only accept New Ideas, not bugs.

Comment: Awesome. Another place would be to post a comment here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/machine-learning-what-is-ml-studio. In my experience with other product teams, they are pretty responsive. HTH.

Comment: `I think they only accept New Ideas, not bugs.` - Oh! I have not tried it but you can post a bug as an idea - "Make this work on Chrome/FF" :).

Comment: I think it's a bug, they seem to fix it now. Wow. ;-)

Comment: Awesome! They do listen :)